# How to get the ad_format on Facebook Ads Api to make a good preview?

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api

Per the documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/generatepreview/,
i need to request ad previews for Facebook ads in a specific format based on the ad format.

Right now, i always request RIGHT_COLUMN_STANDARD, which won't work for some ad.

Is there a way to get directly ad_format ?

Answer (score 0):

There is probably two things you can try. The first is to take a look at the `page_types` in the `target_spec` which belongs to the `AdGroup` and map the target to the type of preview you need.

The second is to take a look at the `object_type` int the `AdCreative` and again map that to the types of preview that are supported.

Comment: I already tried with page_types but when it's equal to "feed", somes previews works with RIGHT_COLUMN_STANDARD and others none.. I think it will be the same with object_type but i will try and back later :) Thx